# Fantasy book with shape shifting dragon warriors

Tags: story-identification, magic, magical-creatures, dragons

Set in a fantasy world with shape shifting Dragon kings and their warriors. They terrorize the humans, and kill those with magic.

The protagonist is the great-grandson of a powerful warlock. He finds out that he has magic, and fights with it to save his new friends, the Griffin, Blackhorse (I think that's his name), some creepy necromancer who is immortal, and Gwen (fellow sorceress), along with the kingdom that the Griffin rules in.

They fight the protagonist's father, the leader of the Dragon kings, the king's Duke, and the creepy sorcerer, who has a curse (when he dies, he changes side from good to bad, or bad to good). I have no clue what this is called, but I want to find out, since I'm out of things to read.

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, was this a book you picked up in the past but had forgotten? Something you heard of secondhand?

Comment: I had a house fire 3 years ago, and was put in an extended stay hotel next to a Barnes and Noble while my house was repaired. I got bored, and went to the book store, where they had volume one of that book, which has the first three books in it. It looked cool, so I bought it, read it, then lost it and forgot it. I only recently remembered it when I saw an Eragon book, which looked similar to the cover of Legends of the Dragonrealm", but I couldn't remember much from it,(like what it was called), but I did remember the details listed above in my question description, and that I had enjoyed it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is likely the *[Legends of the Dragonrealm](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6578970-legends-of-the-dragonrealm-vol-i)* series. It features Cabe Bedlam,

> a mere youth cast adrift in a world where none can be trusted. Yet at his command is a formidable arsenal... a fierce warrior tradition imparted by regal, still-living forbears... the fabulous gifts of the witch Gwen, the ravishing Lady of the Amber... and the magical Horned Blade, the sword that promises its bearer total mastery of the many menacing forms of man and beast"

The antagonists are shapeshifting dragons. Cabe's companions include [The Gryphon](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gryphon), [Darkhorse](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/Darkhorse), [Shade](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/Shade_(character)) (who is the necromancer who is immortal, noted to reincarnate, whereupon he changes between good and evil), and of course [Gwendolyn](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/Gwendolyn_Bedlam), Lady of the Amber.

One of their main antagonists is indeed the protagonist's father, [Azran](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/Azran_Bedlam), who has become the main villain but a major antagonist is [Duke Toma](http://dragonrealm.wikia.com/wiki/Toma), who is far more sane than Azran.

[image: Book Cover - Legends of the Dragonrealm]